# View individual answers in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

I have made a survey with Google Forms. My problem is that I can't see the individual answers. Is that possible or can I only see the overview?

Answer (score 2):

You can see all the individual answers in the spreadsheet. Go to http://docs.google.com, sign in, and find your form/spreadsheet in the document list. Click on it, and you will find a spreadsheet where each response is a single row.